# check in- check out sytem using a barcode scanner

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a check in/out system at a lab I work at. I'm not to experienced at using VBA. I was able to tinker with some formulas to get it to do what I wanted, but I wasn't fully successful in getting all the steps I wanted done.

So what I'm trying to do is check in samples using a barcode followed by a date in the cell right next to it.

I want this formula to apply to `A2000` so I can check in multiple samples. I'm using an input box and I want this input box to be able to detect matched samples and place them in the checked out column `C` followed by a date in the cell right next to it.

I would appreciate any help you guys can give me.

[image]

Here's the code I am currently using.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim myValue As Variant
Dim code As Variant
Dim matchedCell As Variant

myValue = InputBox("Please scan a barcode")
Range("A2").Value = myValue
Set NextCell = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
If NextCell.Row > 1 Then NextCell = NextCell.Offset(1, 0)
Set matchedCell = Range("a2:a2000").Find(what:=code, LookIn:=xlValues,     lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
If myValue = True Then Paste ("C2;C2000")
If Not matchedCell Is Nothing Then matchedCell.Offset(-1, 1).Value = Now

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add data safety, I would differentiate the Check-In and the Check-Out process.
I'm not sure how you get the Code from the scanner ? Copied to prompt automatically ?
Anyway, below is my solution:

1.Transform your table into an excel table (CTRL+T) and name it "STORE_RECORDS" as below:

[image]

2.Create a module and paste following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Check_In()
    Dim Code As String: Code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode", "Scan procedure")
    If Code = "" Then MsgBox ("No code scanned"): Exit Sub
    Dim NbChIn As Integer: NbChIn = Application.CountIf(Range("STORE_RECORDS[CHECK-IN]"), Code)
    Dim NbChOut As Integer: NbChOut = Application.CountIf(Range("STORE_RECORDS[CHECK-OUT]"), Code)
    If NbChIn > NbChOut And NbChIn > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("This item is already Checked-In" & Chr(10) & "Please check it out and retry"): Exit Sub
    Else
        Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Code
        Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = Now
    End If
End Sub

Sub Check_Out()
    Dim Code As String: Code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode", "Scan procedure")
    If Code = "" Then MsgBox ("No code scanned"): Exit Sub
    Dim NbChIn As Integer: NbChIn = Application.CountIf(Range("STORE_RECORDS[CHECK-IN]"), Code)
    Dim NbChOut As Integer: NbChOut = Application.CountIf(Range("STORE_RECORDS[CHECK-OUT]"), Code)
    If NbChIn = NbChOut And NbChIn > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("This item is already Checked-Out" & Chr(10) & "Please check it in and retry"): Exit Sub
    Else
        If Range("STORE_RECORDS[CHECK-IN]").Find(Code, , , xlWhole, , xlPrevious) Is Nothing Then MsgBox ("No match, ask Carlos !"): Exit Sub
        Range("STORE_RECORDS[CHECK-IN]").Find(Code, , ,xlWhole , , xlPrevious).Offset(0, 2) = Code
        Range("STORE_RECORDS[CHECK-IN]").Find(Code, , ,xlWhole , , xlPrevious).Offset(0, 3) = Now
    End If
End Sub
```

3.Link `Check-In` and `Check-Out` buttons to respective procedures and you should be good to go.

Comment: hello I appreciate the help, so I turned my worksheet into a table like you said, then pasted the code and I'm getting a run-time error '1004': method 'range' of object'_global' failed

Comment: Hi there, check that the table name ("STORE_RECORDS") and the table columns names are matching the code (column a is "CHECK-IN" and C is "CHECK-OUT" in the code), you can either change the code or the table but it needs to match

Comment: Hello, I have a follow up question. I'm trying to get this code to apply to other sheets. but every time I try to enter In a code it gives me an error. heres the code I tried using.

Comment: Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        'YOUR CODE HERE
    Next ws